# Difference between Visual Studio Dom Explorer and I.E. F12 tools Dom Explorer

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, debugging, dom

Visual Studio provides a debug window called [DOM Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696638.aspx). Internet Explorer also has a tool called [DOM Explorer that is available from the F12 tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx).

Are these the same tools? If, not what is the difference between them and when should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use  “DOM Explorer”  in Visual Studio that enable the similar code inspect experience like the developer toolbar in IE(F12 DOM Explorer). But it supports more project types.

F12 DOM Explorer: Show you a webpage's integrated structure and allows you to change styles, move HTML elements, and change element attributes without having to edit the page's source files in the IE debugging.

VS DOM Explorer: It also allows the user to select HTML elements, identify CSS rules, and change values without stopping the debugging session for the browser debugging, but it also was used to debug Windows Store apps in the VS IDE.

Just add a screen shot which share the VS dom explorer which also support the HTML page:

[image]

Comment: Can the VS DOM Explorer can be used on any HTML page? The documentation suggests that it can only be used on Windows Store apps, Windows Phone Store apps, and Apps created using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova.

Comment: @Bob, yes, it supports the HTML page in the VS IDE, if you just add a simple HTML page, and then debug this app in your VS IDE, you could find the VS Dom Explorer like the screen shot I added in my answer:)

Comment: @Bob, if it is helpful for you, please mark it as the answer. If not, feel free to let me know:) Have a nice day!